# How to find the website which is built by wordpress or any other software

Tags: wordpress

Let we consider a WordPress website, the question is how, I can identify that the website is built with WordPress or wix or any other software.

Answer (score 0):

1. View source -> Search for 'wp-content'
2. Use a service like: https://www.isitwp.com/
3. More info here: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/site-built-in-wordpress/

I will remove the Techietweets link from your question if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Just press F12, inspect the code and look up for any wordpress tags in the code. Usually you will find out any relation in the code. The body class usually is an indicator. And also the path of the theme has the 'wp-content' keyword. It may be a poor indicator, but something like that is a fast search. If the website itself uses plugings and whatever you will find more information just reading the code.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://xxx.xxx/wp-content/themes/theme/style.css">

      <body class="home page-template-default page page-id-xxx">
```